# Laravel 4 - auth.basic filter session doesn't expire | How to expire auth.basic session

Tags: session, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I have a simple admin area where I can update some aspects of a website. since I'll be the only one accessing it I thought of using the `auth.basic` functionality of Laravel 4.

I built a group on my `routes.php` file that adds the `auth.basic` filter to several resources at once:

```
//routes.php

// Password protected routes
Route::group(['before' => 'auth.basic'], function () {
    Route::get('admin', ['as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'AdminController@index']);
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::resource('pizzas', 'PizzasController');

});
```

The routes are protected (as they should) and I have to fill a pop-up authentication form when I access any of those routes for the first time.

**Here's the problem:** I believe the authenticated session should expire once I close the browser. This is not happening. Even if the browser is closed for hours it still "remembers me".

- I tried setting `'lifetime'   => 0,` on `config/session.php`.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you close the browser, or do you just close the tab? Don't know which OS you are on, but mac os will close completely with cmd-q.

Comment: I close the browser. Tried it on Chrome, Firefox and IE9. They have the same behavior. I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Hm, strange. The onyl thing I can come up with at this point is cookies. Dump them, logged in still ?

Comment: I tried stopping and restarting Apache without success, and finally decided to restart my computer. Now it works on IE9 and Firefox, however, Chrome still keeps my credentials between open/close cycles even after clearing cookies and cache.

Answer (score 0):

To clear `auth.basic` session also, you can use,

```
Auth::logout();
```

Or

```
Auth::clearUserDataFromStorage();
```

See API Doc [here](http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Guard.html#401-413)

Answer (score 0):

Going to `config/session.php` and setting `'lifetime' => 0`, then restarting Windows, fixed it for Firefox and IE9, but not for Chrome on the development machine.

However, Chrome did work as expected when accessing the page from a different computer (not the one serving the page).

Considering nobody will be accessing the site from the server (once it goes live) I'll just live with it.

Answer (score 0):

i think that chrome save auth info and send in any request. So it can be separate from session.

you can check it with chrome dev tools -> net tab. in any request chrome automatically send auth info.

you can check

> auth.basic.once

also.