# authentication in laravel 4: persisting beyond session timeout - is this localhost feature

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I'm creating my first application using Laravel 4.2. The authentication/session is not timing out according to the 'lifetime' setting in app/config/session.php (using 10 which I assume is 10 minutes).

My inspection of the storage in the browser shows a cookie stored upon authentication, but not session information. The cookie is a session expiration cookie. I am not using Remember Me capability.

I am defaulting to "production" for environment.

Can anyone suggest where I might look for the problem or how I can debug it?

Comment: Note there is a similar question related to browser closing/authentication expiration here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19095856/laravel-4-auth-basic-filter-session-doesnt-expire-how-to-expire-auth-basic - but there is no conclusive answer to that question.

Comment: Perhaps fiddling with the 'expire_on_close' in combination with 'lifetime' might help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424607/laravel-4-session-doesnt-expire-after-lifetime-limit

Comment: Ciccio, you nailed it. See answer. Now, how do I give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ciccio gets the credit for the answer here. It was the case that I had 'expire_on_close' set to true in app/config/session.php. That setting apparently disables the 'lifetime' setting. As Ciccio pointed out, it is addressed here [Laravel 4 session doesn't expire after lifetime limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424607/laravel-4-session-doesnt-expire-after-lifetime-limit) . Thanks Ciccio!

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure, maybe you can +1 the comment or something, doesn't matter. Glad I could help.